# How to set editor for a column programmatically in a grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, extjs-grid

I have a `Ext.grid.Panel` with a set of columns. This grid is filtered, and depending on the filter I would like to define an editor for a column.

My grid:

```
Ext.define('Mb.view.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    columns: [
        {text: 'Order #', dataIndex: 'id'},
        {text: 'Action', dataIndex: 'type',
            renderer: function(value){
                if(value == 'BP') return Lang._('Veuillez choisir')
                 return ''
            }
        },
```

Now I would like to do something like:

```
var panel = Mb.app.getView('MyPanel');
if (condition == true) {
    panel.getColumns[1].setEditor({
        xtype: 'textfield',
        ...
    })
}
```

Obviously the methods `getColumns` and `setEditor` do not exist. I therefore need another method to activate an editor on that column.
I didn't find a method to access the column definitions to modifiy them and to rerender the grid afterwards.

Can you give me a hint in which direction to search ? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the docs for `getEditor()` on [`Ext.grid.column.Column`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-method-getEditor). If you are using an Editing plugin, the plugin provides implementation for `getEditor()`, as well as `setEditor()`. Based on column being edited and any custom logic you implement, you could implement a custom `getEditor()` method to return whatever editor instance you want based on the circumstances.

The documentation says:

```
getEditor( record, defaultField ) : Ext.form.field.Field
```

This really tells a small part of the truth.

- `getEditor` is not only a method of `Ext.grid.column.Column`, but also a config option.
- If `getEditor` is defined as config option function get's called as `getEditor( record )` and needs to return a `Ext.grid.CellEditor`.
- This will work with the cellediting plugin, but not with the rowediting plugin.

Here is an example of a column configuration. It will create a combobox only on selected rows :

```
columns: [{
    text: 'Action', dataIndex: 'action', 
    getEditor: function(record){
        if( my logic ){
            return Ext.create('Ext.grid.CellEditor', {
                field: Ext.create( 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
                    forceSelection: true,
                    store: [[1, 'Option 1'], [2, 'Option 2']]
                })
            })
        } else return false;
    }
},
```

Comment: I think I get the idea: I write a `getEditor(record)` and return whatever a field a like for the row. But where do I need to define it ? As a config option of the column ?  
This also means that there can be different editors on a row basis, am I right ?

Comment: On the other hand, when I'd like to use the `setEditor` method of the column, I need a reference to the column, and Idon't know how to get this from the grid object.

Comment: Yeah, you simply define "getEditor()" for the column definition. Check out this fiddle for an example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2d

Comment: This is heavily undocumented. I edit your answer to include your example.